# JSF table pagination

Tags: jsf, datatable, pagination, myfaces, tomahawk

I am a newbie with JSF. Currently I have the problem with keeping the state of data-table list pagination.

The problem is when a user edits a row of a list which is not in the first page of data-table, after completing his action, page navigation returns to the first initial page of the list while we need to return to the previous page that user has been editing.

A complete Scenario:

- In the list page there are 100 rows of records, and each page shows 20 rows,
- User navigates to the 3th page, and selects one of the rows in order to edit the record.
- Backing ListBean calls the EditBean that navigate the page to edit page.
- User update the record information and backing Editbean calls back the ListBean.
- ListBean refresh the Datamodel and navigate back to the list page, but the state of the pagination that user initially had edited is lost.

What is the best approach to return back the page to the previous page that user has been editing?

Myface 1.2.7 and Tomahawk taglib 1.0 has been used in the project. Pages consist of t:dataTable.

Thanks.